# How to compile drivers on 3.0.32-yocto-standard

Tags: intel-fpga, yocto

I am new to **yocto** and developing drivers. I got source code (`alter_driver.c` and `Makefile`) for the drivers but I don't have any idea how to compile and get `altera_driver.ko` file, so that I can load that drivers and use them.

The version of yocto kernel is **3.0.32-yocto-standard** which I got from terminal command `uname -r`.

Please help me in compiling the drivers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the [Yocto Kernel Development Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html) (the link is to current version: you should use the one for your Yocto release). If the only thing you have is a out-of-tree module, see part 2.5.2 which explains how to create a recipe for your driver.

The short version is: make a copy of the [example recipe](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-skeleton/recipes-kernel/hello-mod), add your sources in the files/-directory, modify the Makefile to build your sources... but read the manual, it's pretty good.

Also, the [Kernel Lab](https://www.yoctoproject.org/training/kernel-lab) may be useful: it mostly talks about working with a full kernel but also covers an out-of-tree module example (lab 4).